# Nginx force download specific extensions

Tags: linux, nginx

I'm using this code inside server block to force download mp3 files

```
location ~ /mp3folder/.+\.mp3$ {
 types {
  application/octet-stream;
 }
}
```

I want to specify multiple extensions like mp4, wmv, flv ... what changes should make for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
/mp3folder/.+\.(mp3|mp4|wmv|flv)$
```